# Как вернуть секунды из даты?

Tags: javascript

```
let d = new Date('2021-07-25T07:00:00+06:00');

console.log(d.getSeconds());
```

Но ответ 0.
Как вернуть секунды до этой даты

Comment: А какой ответ вы ожидали? Может вам надо `d.getTime() / 1000`

Comment: или от даты имеется ввиду "от сегодня, до тогда"?

Comment: Там и есть 00 секунд.

Comment: Похоже, что "XY Problem"...

Answer (score 1):

```js
let d = new Date('2021-07-25T07:00:00+06:00');

console.log(d / 1000);  // от 1970
console.log((d - Date.now()) / 1000); // от сейчас до даты
```

Comment: либо так еще `(d - new Date) / 1000`